# Estimate cycle of the pump per day

Tags: pumps, hydraulics, hydrology

I have a pump system that is on for 5 days. For the entire 5 days, there are 3 days that the pump system is able to complete on and off cycle.

I want to estimate the cycle of the pump (on/off) per day?

My solution is: 3/5 = 0.6 cycles/day

I am not 100% sure on this.

Appreciate any thoughts on this. Thanks

Comment: what is your question? ... you did not ask anything

Comment: @jsotola I'd like to confirm with the logic of my solution, with some explanation of possible. Thanks

Comment: That is how one might take an average.  Whether using an average is appropriate is a different matter that requires understanding what the resulting value is supposed to represent